# add CORS policy on NGINX server

Tags: nginx, web-server, cors

i'm having difficulties adding CORS policy to my NGINX server.
I have pointed DNS server to server but the problem in CORS policy is not working. When accessing subdomain.domain.com everything works fine but problem is on location block. domain/path is giving a CORS policy error.
Any way to fix this?

```
no font @has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you received one answer already - better than nothing, but in my opition it's code can only be used as initial iteration.

Code below, ***which I'm not the original author of*** (which was found as a gist on GitHub), is way better at nandling CORS. And is especially nicer for not using wildcards. Still has some places to polish, but I'm using it.

```
    set $cors '';
    # Extend the list of XSS-whilelisted domains by adding more
    if ($http_origin ~ '^http[s]*?://(foo\.bar|.+\.foo\.bar|fou\.baar|.+\.fou\.baar)') {
        set $cors T;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        set $cors "${cors}O";
    }

    if ($cors = 'T') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
    }

    if ($cors = 'O') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

    if ($cors = 'TO') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a lot of information on how to enable CORS on nginx with configuration examples and a lot of background information here: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html